# Set unique environment variables for docker container services in gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-network

From the Gitlab Runner [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#network-per-build):

> Note: Unlike legacy container links used in other network modes, Docker environment variables will **Not** be shared across the containers.

How do you set up the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to have unique enviroment variables for each service container?